# How to get a postdoc without publications in "top" venues?

Tags: publications, career-path, job-search, postdocs

I am a Ph.D. student in computer vision at a North American university. I have a very hard and limited problem in my thesis and I could not publish in top conferences such as CVPR, ICCV, PAMI,... I published 3 IEEE conferences and I submitted 1 journal (under revision) in PRL. I was very autonomous (99%).

I am looking for a postdoc in north America, Japan or Singapore. I remark that all positions demand that the candidate should have published in top conferences or top journals.

So, can I have a postdoc opportunity or I have to forget it and  look for an industrial post?

Comment: Your advisor will have better insight into what postdoc employers in your specific subfield will be looking for.  **Talk to your advisor.**

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks for your comment.  I write this question to get more advice and more point of view

Comment: @NateEldredge As the OP is saying that he was autonomous, that means his/her prof. was not involved. Now, what can exactly he/she can discuss with the prof.?

Comment: @BetterEnglish What is your long-term goal? These days it can be tough to stay in academia without a strong publication record even through your PhD years.

Comment: In reality, it's not unheard of for people to state specific conference/journal requirements in a job ad, and then be more flexible in practice if there are other reasons to believe that you're useful. Putting requirements like that in a job ad gives people something "objective" on which to base the rejection of weaker candidates; it doesn't mean that they're going to reject good candidates out of hand (it wouldn't make sense for them to do that). In reality, most sensible professors will look at individual people who are applying and assess them on their merits.

Comment: @Coder even if the advisor knows little about her or his student, (s)he does/should know the field, and can thus advise on what expectations are reasonable.

Comment: @Coder, thanks so much for your comment and analysis

Answer (score 3):

If your CV is weak and you are worried about being filtered out based on that, you can ask your advisor to contact people and recommend you directly. Additionally, you could try contacting senior scientists that you met in conferences and were excited about your work.